# how to close a oledbconnection object?

Tags: c#, ado.net

ok so i have a Class A that implements method M1 that takes an excel path and a sheet name, and returns an OledbDataReader .
Class B calls the method M1 , does some stuff with the OledbDataReader, then closes the OledbDataReader. but how can i Close The OLEDBConnection object? i dont have access to it because M1 in Class A opened the connection ! any ideas? thank youu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remodel your class A like this:

```
class HelperClass : IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposed;
    private OleDbConnection _connection;

    public HelperClass()
    {
        _connection = << open the conection >>;
    }

    public OledbDataReader GetOpenedReader()
    {
        return << open your reader here with the connection >>;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            _disposed = true;

            _connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Then it's the resposibility of the calling class to use your class like this:

```
using (var helperClass = new HelperClass())
{
    // call the method that opens the reader and uses it
}
```

Comment: first of all,thanks for ur detailed answer. im really new to this . ive never heard of "helper classes before". do u suggest any good tutorial that would help me  understand better wat u sent me ? and about the code you sent me , i will use it  , and then in class B that calls the method of Class A i will first call the GetOpenerReader, then call the Dispose method..right ?

Comment: In this example, `HelperClass` is class `A`. The example with `using` is calling the `Dispose` for you. If you use a class like this, `Dispose` is automatically called.

Answer (score 1):

IF you have a using in your outer class like so.

```
 using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
 {



}
```

This will dispose of it all in good time...

Answer (score 0):

Implement [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) in class A